# Sort Divs by inline "style" attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possibile to sort divs by an inline width attribute (highest first)?

For example that are my divs:

```
  <div style="width: 30.8px"></div>
  <div style="width: 10.45px"></div>
  <div style="width: 20px"></div>
```

I was looking for something like this, but it only works with div content ;(

```
$('.list li').sort(sortDescending).appendTo('.list');

function sortDescending(a, b) {
    var date1 = $(a).find("div").text()
    var date2 = $(b).find("div").text();

    return $(b).find("div").text() - $(a).find("div").text();
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier to just sort by the width of the element itself. This has two benefits; firstly you don't have to dissect the string to get the width value and secondly (and more importantly) you can then set the `width` property in an external stylesheet and the logic will still work. Try this:

```js
$('div').sort(function(a, b) {
  return $(a).width() > $(b).width() ? -1 : $(a).width() < $(b).width() ? 1 : 0;
}).appendTo('.list');
```

```css
div div {
  border: 1px solid #C00;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 5px;
}
#foo {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <div style="width: 30.8px"></div>
  <div style="width: 10.45px"></div>
  <div style="width: 20px"></div>
  <div id="foo"></div>
</div>
```

Note that your selector is aiming for `li` elements yet your sample is using `div` elements. I'm just presuming this is just an oversight when writing the question.

Comment: Thx for your fast support, I will try it! Back in some min.

Comment: Ok, have have modify your script a bit, now it works for me!